# Remove label for dynamicaly created checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to delete both the checkbox and the label on success of json call.
I have tried alsorts of code found here but so far have only managed to remove the checkbox.

**Checkbox and label code**

```
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="delete[]" class="checkboxAdmin" /><?php echo $row['name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['email']; ?></label>
```

**Jquery code**

```
    $(".delete_admin_but").click(function() {

$.post("includes/delete_admin.inc.php",{ checked_box : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},function(json)   {
    if(json.result === "success") {
        $("#deleteAdminError").html(json.message);
        $("input:checkbox:checked").remove();

//  $('.add_intern').get(0).reset();
    }else{
        $("#deleteAdminError").html(json.message);
    }
});
        });//submit click
```

The checkbox and label are dynamically created, and the only code I have found is for checkboxes and labels that are embeded in code with specific id that is easily identified, I hope that makes sense

Comment: `$(".checkbox")[0].remove();`?

Comment: take the parent out and child (checkbox) gets taken out too

Comment: What is wrapping the label and check? Can you empty the closest("div") for example

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Isn't this what he asked for? To remove the label containing the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well...

Replace

`$("input:checkbox:checked").remove();`

With

`$("input:checkbox:checked").parent().remove();`

Removing the parent (in your case that's the label) will remove the label and input altogether

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried this earlier, but I tried it again and it worked, thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the checkbox parent an remove it:

```
if(json.result === "success") {
    $("#deleteAdminError").html(json.message);
    $("input:checkbox:checked").parent('label').remove();
}
```